# How to group then select elements into new class in LINQ (C# preferably)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I am trying to get my head around grouping, and then building my own class in the result. I know the result of a group by is an IGrouping collection but can I access the rows as they are being built to add a couple of flags to them with a custom class?

I have a class called FlightTimes with some data, but I'd like to append some data to the rows, like a FlagRedEye. So I created a class called FlightTimeResult with the original FlightTime class data plus the flag.

Can I do this? I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. I like to use strong types until I understand what is going on. I had to change a few things to protect my client so I apologize for any syntax errors.

```
IGrouping<string, FlightTimeResult> FlightTimes =
               ( from flighttimes in schedules.FlightTimes
                 group flighttimes by flighttimes.FlightType.ToString()
                     into groupedFlights
                 select new FlightTimeResult( )
                 {
                     FlightTimeData = FlightTime,   // Original class data
                     FlagRedEye = (FlightTime.departureTime.Hour >= 0 &&
                                  FlightTime.departureTime.Hour < 6) // Extra flag
                 } )
```

The goal is to have a collection of FlightTimesResult (FlightTime + extra flag) grouped by FlightType.  Not sure how to access the individual FlightTime rows in the query 'select new FlightTimeResult()'

Do i need to use a nested query on the groupedFlights?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Which `FlightTime` do you want to access?

Comment: I re-used FlightTimes twice up there sorry. Changing names of variables was gonna get me I knew it. I just wanted to get the original FlightTime list but append a flag to each element in it. Trying to keep from the operation multiple times in the page code. Then of course group that by FlightType.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easiest achieved by calling Linq functions explicitly in following way:

```
IQueryable<IGrouping<string, FlightTimeResult>> query 
         = schedules.FlightTimes.GroupBy(
               ft => ft.FlightType.ToString(), // key 
               ft => new FlightTimeResult() { // your constructed objects for key
                    FlightTimeData = ft,
                    FlagRedEye = (ft.departureTime.Hour >= 0 && ft.departureTime.Hour < 6)
                    }
               );
```

The [two-argument `GroupBy` operator function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549270.aspx) takes two lambdas as arguments - one for extracting keys, second for extracting values for it.

Also keep in mind that **group by** operation (be it `group itm by key` construction or `GroupBy` call) returns a collection of `IGrouping<,>`s - not a single one.

Thus it will be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<,>>` or `IQueryable<IGrouping<,>>`.

Comment: Nice. I will try that too. Thank you very much. As far as speed is the Method-type of querying faster? I need every millisecond.

Comment: @Bryce but this might be because of omitting `select`. As a matter of fact, method-type (`.OrderBy`) and construction-type (`order ... by .. into`) calls are equivalent. Compiler simply turns the latter into the former during compilation.

Comment: How costly is the conversion I wonder. If I just use Method-type will I gain any significant/measurable performance? I mean everywhere, not just for this issue.

Comment: @Bryce I don't think so. I might have used "may" instead of "should" in previous comments. I think you should assume they are equivalent.

Comment: Oh duh you said compiler. That is my sign to call it a day. Thank you and have a good one!

Comment: @Bryce no problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if you like it (be it mine or somebody's else).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track. Instead of grouping FlightTimes by FlightType, try building FlightTimeResults and grouping those by FlightType instead:

```
var results = 
    from ft in schedules.FlightTimes
    group new FlightTimeResult
        {
            FlightTimeData = ft,
            FlagRedeye = ft.DepartureTime.Hour >= 0 && ft.DepartureTime.Hour < 6
        }
    by ft.FlightType.ToString()
    into groupedFlights
    select groupedFlights;
```